# mysql Use Navicat connect to remote database using SSL

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench, navicat

I am trying to connect to a remote server database via navicat / sequel pro but having time outs.

I have mysql host, username, password, sql name and tried using ssl certificate but no luck. Not sure what I am missing.

What are some of the best process to test the connection via command line and how can I get this to work

Thanks

Comment: Timeouts mean the server is not responding at all.  This likely means a firewall is blocking access from your machine to the MySQL server.

Comment: try to connect `mysql -h IP -u USERNAME \ --ssl-ca=ca.pem \ --ssl-cert=client-cert.pem \ --ssl-key=client-key.pem -p`

https://www.howtoforge.com/tutorial/how-to-enable-ssl-and-remote-connections-for-mysql-on-centos-7/